# DocuSign C# WebApi Error: 'Unexpected PEM type'

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, docusignapi, webapi

Using the VS2019 Docusign Extension. I chose WebAPI and JWT Authentication.  A sample project was generated.

I inserted one line of code to call in the sample WeatherForecastController's Get method: JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT();

All of the expected params are being picked up from the app.config file but I am getting the Error: 'Unexpected PEM type':

[image]

Here is what my app.config files looks like that was generated by the Docusign Extension.

[image]

And one final piece of info:
[image]

In the docusign portal, I have tried setting the Authentication type to both "Code Grant" or "Implicit". The one that I actually want it JWT Authentication but that is not an explicit option, so which one should I be using for JWT Auth?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix to the root of this question, which is that the key-file-as-string-config-param works in Esign 4.1.1 but not in version 5.2:

[DocuSign .NET SDK - Esign DLL - Dealing with changes in Docusign Config Params regarding Error: 'Unexpected PEM type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919340/docusign-net-sdk-esign-dll-dealing-with-changes-in-docusign-config-params-r/66919341#66919341)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`?

Comment: try Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(), where? To get the RSAKey?

Comment: replace Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() with Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()

Comment: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() seems to have worked but now. I am getting the "consent_required." I see Larry's post about granting consent, but I see no way to actually pass in the redirect URL with this call to Request a JWT Token. Does anyone have a working example of how to do this with just a WebAPI controller and not MVC? The documentation is too fragmented. And the generated project is inadequate, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you generated RSA keypair in the Apps and Keys page for that IK.
You should have done so and then copy/pasted the key directly to private.key file (using notepad, not VS). The file has to be *exactly* as is from the DocuSign portal to avoid this error.
(the lines -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- are part of the key, cannot be removed, everything is required)

You can also try to replace:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()
```

with

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()
```

Videos related to using C# with DocuSign:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9WypM0WarM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-PAstwlLSc

Comment: I have used the "Quick Start" Process on the DocuSign Developer page, and it will generate all the security credentials and RSA and save the generated project to a zip which the Developer can download and run. 

What is generated, is an Asp.Net Core MVC project. In this project the RSA Key is saved to the project as a file. This project works. But I want a WebAPI version, not using MVC Controllers.

This differs from the WebAPI Project that is generated with the Docusign Extension that I already described.

Try it yourself, please. User the Docusign Extension to create a WebAPI Project.

Comment: It works just fine for me. The issue is that you don't have the full RSA key. You removed the lines -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
It's all required. I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried with the lines as well, and it didn't work. But, I used your suggestion of loading the external file with System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(), and that did work, but I encountered other errors. And so I have fallen back to the MVC project that is generated on the DocuSign developer quick start page. That works. 

Inbar, it would be really helpful if you could upload a youtube video of all the steps you are using to a) get an an access token, and b) execute the embedded signing ceremony using just the web api controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a fix to the root of this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919340/docusign-net-sdk-esign-dll-dealing-with-changes-in-docusign-config-params-r/66919341#66919341