# DocuSign .NET SDK - Esign DLL - Dealing with changes in Docusign Config Params regarding Error: 'Unexpected PEM type'

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi, .net-5

In Esign version 4.1.1, the VS2019 Docusign project code generators produce this type of config file:

[image]

Note that the developer must copy and paste the private key generated on the DocuSign "Quick Start" page into the VS2019 Docusign Project Wizard. The key is converted into a string, with each line in the original key file represented with a carriage return.

Using the private key value in this fashion, inline, with all the other params was very convenient.

This "RSAKey" param value *does* work with the 4.1.1 version. But *does not* with the 5.2 version.

In the Esign 5.2 version, we are now in the Asp.Net Core 3.1/.NET 5 style of code, so we now have this configuration file format:

[image]

This won't work with Esign 5.2. I surmise the change in 5.2 is this - the Docusign server generates a hash value of the key *file*, and if the generated hash of the key *file* submitted by an external client does not match, an "Unknown PEM File" error is sent back. I am trying to highlight the nuance that the first “gate” on the DocuSign server checks the *file itself*, not the *RSA key inside the file*.

The ramification, if true, is that we now have to treat the key file with kid gloves. If I wanted to store/retrieve this file from a remote source, I would need to take great care that not a single byte was changed/added/removed. This will require careful testing. As you can see from my sample appsettings.json above, I am forced to add "KeyFilePath" param in order to grab the physical file, which means I must always have it on hand in my project or be able to remotely load it (intact byte-wise) from a remote source. This increases the burden on the developer and maintenance staff considerably.

Ideally, what we need is a way to get that capability to put the key-file-as-a-string back into the config params.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is by using https://base64.guru/ .

Using the "File-to-Base64" option allow me to provide this as a string parameter in a normal config file.

Then the C# code to use it looks like this:

```
var cred = LoadDocusingConfigIntoObject();

byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cred.PrivateKey);

                this.OAuthToken = docusignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                    cred.IntegrationKey,
                    cred.ImpersonatedUserId,
                    cred.AuthServer,
                    buffer,
                    1,
                    scopes
                );
```